# Mapping vector of values to custom value

Tags: r

I have vector of values like some Job Positions lets say

```
JobPosition <- as.data.frame(rep(c("Helpdesk","Data Engineer","Salesman"), 5))
```

I want each Helpdesk associate with JobPosition 1, each DE with JobPosition2, each Salesman with JobPosition3. I know how to make them random strings using dplyr but not how to convert them into desired string with incremental number

Expected output

```
Job position    NewJobPosition
Helpdesk        JobPosition1
Data engineer   JobPosition2
Salesman        JobPosition3
Helpdesk        JobPosition1
Data engineer   JobPosition2
Salesman        JobPosition3
```

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Comment: done. but I dont know how many unique position i'll find as I've large dataset, these 3 are just to show the pattern. Each job position should have JobPosition+X where X is the number, incrementing for each unique job position found in a column

Comment: See [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618).

Comment: What do you suggest to merge? I don't know how many occurrences will be in the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do,

```
  JobPosition %>% mutate(number = as.integer(fct_inorder(Position))) %>% mutate(NewJobPosition = paste0('JobPosition', number)) %>% select(Position, NewJobPosition)

        Position NewJobPosition
1       Helpdesk   JobPosition1
2  Data Engineer   JobPosition2
3       Salesman   JobPosition3
4       Helpdesk   JobPosition1
5  Data Engineer   JobPosition2
6       Salesman   JobPosition3
7       Helpdesk   JobPosition1
8  Data Engineer   JobPosition2
9       Salesman   JobPosition3
10      Helpdesk   JobPosition1
11 Data Engineer   JobPosition2
12      Salesman   JobPosition3
13      Helpdesk   JobPosition1
14 Data Engineer   JobPosition2
15      Salesman   JobPosition3
```

**Data**

```
JobPosition <- data.frame('Position' = rep(c("Helpdesk","Data Engineer","Salesman"), 5))
```

Comment: One question: What if all values are ints or doubles? This approach doesnt work then, at least for me

Comment: You may need to convert it to character/string.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (you can reduce code if you want, kept it like this for legibility)

```
library(dplyr)

JobPosition <- as.data.frame(rep(c("Helpdesk","Data Engineer","Salesman"), 5))
names(JobPosition) <- "Job Position"

#Give every unique Jobposition a seperate number
position_numbers <- unique(JobPosition) %>%
  mutate(NewJobDecision = paste0("JobPosition", row_number()))

#Merge them
merge(y = JobPosition, 
      x = position_numbers)
```

Comment: Can I do that in one function calling? Id have at least 15 columns to do that Something like `dataset %>%
  position_numbers <- unique(dataset$`Job Position`) %>%
  mutate(NewJobDecision = paste0("JobPosition", row_number()))`